# Declaring Array in C with variable length

Tags: arrays, c, fibonacci

This block of code gives me the fibonacci numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n; //integer overflow error for n > 47

    printf("How many Fibonacci numbers?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int fibs[n];

    fibs[0] = 0;
    fibs[1] = 1;

    printf("%d ", fibs[0]);
    printf("%d ", fibs[1]);

    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        fibs[i] = fibs[i - 2] + fibs[i - 1];
        printf("%d ", fibs[i]);
    }
    return 0;
    //gives 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 for n = 10

}
```

But this gives me the wrong output but no errors

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, fibs[n];//change

    printf("How many Fibonacci numbers?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    fibs[0] = 0;
    fibs[1] = 1;

    printf("%d ", fibs[0]);
    printf("%d ", fibs[1]);

    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        fibs[i] = fibs[i - 2] + fibs[i - 1];
        printf("%d ", fibs[i]);
    }
    return 0;
    //gives 0 1 for n = 10
}
```

I know it definitely has something to do with the array and its size not being defined but I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is the problem.

Could someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result. Also, can you please point out what the differences are between the two code examples (apart from an extra comment)?

Comment: It's the same code in both? (Though you *really* need to check to see if `scanf()` succeeded before using `n`.

Comment: Your two programs are exacly the same apart from a different comment .  To improve the question, you should only include the version that is NOT working , and show the exact input that you provided to the program which causes the unexpected behaviour; and describe how the behaviour differs from what you expected

Comment: You really don't need to keep an array of all fibonacci numbers. At no point are you really using more than 3 integers.

Comment: `int n, fibs[n];` causes undefined behaviour as you try to make an array whose size is an uninitialized variable .  What did you expect to happen really?

Comment: @M.M, I'm sorry I have corrected the mistake and also pointed out the changes and the output it gives for an input

Comment: Re “But this gives me … no errors”: The compiler almost certainly issued a warning message. Clang, GCC, and MSVC do. Do not ignore warning messages. With Clang or GCC, use `-Werror` to elevate warnings to errors. With MSVC, use `/WX`. If you are using an IDE, look for an option to elevate warnings to errors.

Comment: @M.M: Novices who write `int n, fibs[n];` expect the array to have size `n` after they set the value of `n`. We have seen this previously, and posing rhetorical questions like this intended to suggest the declaration is nonsensical does not have that result, because the author has a mental model that is not unreasonable; another programming language certainly could support a dynamic array feature in which the array size is bound to a variable. If something is wrong and does not make sense in C, then state that directly: The array size is defined at the time of definition and not changed later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int n, fibs[n];` attempts to define an array using `n` for the length, but `n` has not been initialized, so its value is not determined. Common consequences include:

- The definition behaves as if `n` has some small value, possibly zero, and then the following code attempts to store values in the array but overruns the memory reserved for it and thus destroys other data needed by the program.
- The definition behaves as if `n` has some large value, causing the stack to overflow and the program to be terminated.

For example, storing 0 to to `fibs[0]` or 1 to `fibs[1]` might write to the memory reserved for `n`. Then the `for` loop terminates without executing any iterations because the test `i < n` is false.

Answer (score 0):

The one big thing that I see in your code is the line `int n, fibs[n];`. The variable n is located on the stack since it's a local variable.  That means that it's value can literally be anything before it's initialized.  And since you are declaring an array using that value, the array has a random, unknown length.  If it works, then that is purely coincidence.  This is why your first code version works because the array is declared *AFTER* the scanf which initializes n.  I think a better way of creating an array with a variable number of array elements is to use malloc instead...

```
int n, *fibs;
printf("How many Fibinocci numbers?\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
fibs = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
if (fibs == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate sufficient memory for operation.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Then you can use array indices fibs[0], fibs[1], etc... to access different locations in the block of memory.

Why does this work? Because `int fibs[n]` is *LIKE* a pointer to a block of memory.  Technically, they are not the same, but you can generally use a pointer to a block of memory as an array.  This will only work with single dimensional arrays because the compiler has no idea how many columns there are.  But to work around that, you can compute that manually like this (i is the row, j is the column):

array[i * columns + j];